# When are next SO moderator elections scheduled?

Tags: support, status-completed, moderators, moderator-election

Looking at the [elections page](https://stackoverflow.com/election) I noticed that the elections in the last year were held more or less in this period of the year.

Assuming the same for this year, I expected to find *advertizing* of this event everywhere in the site, being it very relevant for the community. But **I couldn't find it anywhere!**

Am I blind or there's no sign of these incoming elections? Is it possible that they have even not been scheduled? If instead they have been scheduled, where can we find that information?

Comment: Elections are not held at regular intervals. They are held as needed. Apparently they are not needed...?

Comment: Cody, a current mod, said: [*Lots of upheaval at the corporate level. The last election was back in 2019. We are due for another one, but no timeline as of yet when it'll happen. Probably later this year.*](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/6?m=48762453)

Comment: @rene I don't understand why you posted a python chat link..

Comment: There was a new election system in the works. Although the one working on the election system [was Shog](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2292/what-is-the-status-of-the-increase-in-repuation-thresholds-for-privileges/2299#comment6188_2299)... I imagine at some point they'll announce new elections, although it's not unlikely that's after they finish all the new things related moderation being planned/built right now (e.g. "moderator council", moderator training, etc)

Comment: @000 Because that's where the quote comes from

Comment: Keep in mind you need a CM to start an election and they are stretched thin at the moment. Also they don't want to run many elections in parallel and there are other sites in the network that need elections because they lost (most of) their mod team due to the events last year.

Comment: @rene thanks. I wasn't aware of the CMs role (it is my first year in this community).

Comment: *Who is* the current main Stack Overflow Community Manager? Does that land on Tim Post now?

Comment: @TravisJ AFAIK there is no single contact any more. The load is taken by the remaining CM's

Comment: There’s never been a “main Stack Overflow Community Manager”. All the CMs work together as a team, just like the moderators. Juan is the team lead for the CMs. Tim Post isn’t really doing CM work anymore, and hasn’t for quite some time. @Travis

Comment: @CodyGray - Perhaps not by title, but by function there certainly has been. I realize its a team, but there have historically been staff members who were at the forefront of responses here. Most recently, it was Shog and Jon. Now that they are both departed from the company, there is a clear void.

Comment: Just gonna be frank here - I'm really not interested in another popularity contest in which people who Meta has never really seen in any meaningful capacity suddenly show up, wanting to take on the dumpster fires we've been having to deal with, using a lot of flowery language about what they will or won't do, when at the end of the day, we just need people with a spine and who have been through a few winters here and can read the temperature of the room.

Comment: @Makoto: I guess the fluid in a thermometer counts as spinal fluid if you think about it...

Comment: There was something about getting a new moderator agreement finished before starting elections but then elections are already been done currently elsewhere on the network, so maybe that is not so much of a problem anymore.

Comment: @Makoto thats the rub isn't it, everyone over 300 rep gets the notification to vote, so anything but candidate score/rep and presentation in the nom doesn't really matter. The questions and answers and just general activity is not examined by the vast majority of the voters.

Comment: That's correct, @Trilarion. The moderator agreement is currently in the works, and slated to be previewed to moderators within the next week or so. I suspect that the revised moderator agreement is probably a prerequisite for holding an election on a site as large as Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The next [moderator election](https://stackoverflow.com/election/12) will begin with the nomination phase on [2020-07-06 20:00:00Z](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/fixedtime.html?iso=20200706T200000) (*approx. 12 days from now*).

To calculate your candidate score, and find out what election badges you are missing, I'm developing a [chat bot here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190503/electionbot-development), which will respond if you type "`what is my candidate score`".

Comment: So I have 6 to 8 days left to work on my stats ...

Comment: Any word on the moderator agreement?

Comment: @george was already presented to the mods on teams, and probably going through another revision based on feedback, and/or dev work is required to be able to allow mods to accept the new one?