# What conditions determine / what decision process leads to a new moderator election starting?

Tags: support, moderator-election

I've noticed that [the moderator elections](https://stackoverflow.com/election) are relatively periodic- pretty much one or sometimes two every year. So the basic premise of my question is that there's a *degree* of schedule / intentional periodicity to when election happening. But what I'm seeking to understand is the fact that it's not "perfectly" periodic: (though recently, it seems like it happens every year-and-a-bit) There doesn't seem to be a set date every year.

So how (or more deeply, "why") does a new election start? Is there a set of concrete conditions that- when triggered- sound an alarm that more mods are needed? Or is it more off-the-cuff, like the current mod team telling staff that they need more hands?

I'm relatively new here (have only been present for the 2022 election), so I'm trying to understand how this works. Forgive me if I misunderstand something. I've looked at all the [support](/questions/tagged/support) questions tagged [moderator-election](/questions/tagged/moderator-election), and didn't find an answer to this question. The closest thing I found was [When are next SO moderator elections scheduled?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394585/11107541), where the answer was about a specific election, and not about elections in general.

Comment: I think the reference you're looking for is [When do moderator elections take place?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99512) on MSE. The summary of which is there is no formal process or timeline, but a check in annually which typically correlates to an election every year (and a bit).

Comment: @HenryEcker perhaps this can be closed as a cross-site duplicate?

Comment: @Nike well no, since cross-site closure is not supported in any capacity.

Comment: @Gimby we can vote to close, then click "community specific reason", then click "other".